# <Terminated> Program Files

Tags: java, eclipse, poo

Cuando ejecuto el siguiente codigo en la consola me muestra lo siguiente en la consola: Window[Java Application] C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe
¿Saben porque sale esto :'c?

```html
package formularios;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Window {

   public static void main(String[] args){
 
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
      try {
      Window window = new Window();
       window.setVisible(true);
      } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }
    });
   }   
    public Window() {
        
        // Crear un JFrame y un JTable
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JTable table = new JTable(); 
        
        // Crear la tabla y los nombres de las columnas
        Object[] columns = {"Id","First Name","Last Name","Age"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columns);
        
        // Establecer el modelo de la tablaa
        table.setModel(model);
        
        // Cambiar el color de fondo de la tabla, el tamaño
       // de la letra y el color y la altura de las filas
        table.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        table.setForeground(Color.black);
        Font font = new Font("",1,22);
        table.setFont(font);
        table.setRowHeight(30);
        
        // Crear JTextField
        JTextField txtTitulo = new JTextField();
        JTextField txtAutor = new JTextField();
        JTextField txtAno = new JTextField();
        JTextField txtGeneroMateria = new JTextField();
        
        // Crear botones
        JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Agregar");
        JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Borrar");
        JButton btnUpdate = new JButton("Actualizar");     
        
        txtTitulo.setBounds(20, 220, 100, 25);
        txtAutor.setBounds(20, 250, 100, 25);
        txtAno.setBounds(20, 280, 100, 25);
        txtGeneroMateria.setBounds(20, 310, 100, 25);
        
        btnAdd.setBounds(150, 220, 100, 25);
        btnUpdate.setBounds(150, 265, 100, 25);
        btnDelete.setBounds(150, 310, 100, 25);
        
        // Crear un panel de dezlizamiento
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        pane.setBounds(0, 0, 880, 200);
        
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        frame.getContentPane().add(pane);
        
        // Agregar campos de texto
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtTitulo);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtAutor);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtAno);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtGeneroMateria);
    
        // Agregar botones a la ventana
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnAdd);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnDelete);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnUpdate);
        
        // Crear una lista de objetos
        Object[] row = new Object[4];
        
        // Accion de agregar una fila a la tabla
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             
                row[0] = txtTitulo.getText();
                row[1] = txtAutor.getText();
                row[2] = txtAno.getText();
                row[3] = txtGeneroMateria.getText();
                
                // Agregar una fila a la tabla
                model.addRow(row);
            }
        });
        
        // boton eliminar fila
        btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
                // i es el valor de la fila seleccionada
                int i = table.getSelectedRow();
                if(i >= 0){
                    // Eliminar una fila de la tabla
                    model.removeRow(i);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Error al eliminar");
                }
            }
        });
        
        // Obtener los datos de la fila seleccionada
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            
            // i = the index of the selected row
            int i = table.getSelectedRow();
            
            txtTitulo.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
            txtAutor.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
            txtAno.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
            txtGeneroMateria.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
        }
        });
        
        // Actualizar fila
        btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             
                // i = the index of the selected row
                int i = table.getSelectedRow();
                
                if(i >= 0) 
                {
                   model.setValueAt(txtTitulo.getText(), i, 0);
                   model.setValueAt(txtAutor.getText(), i, 1);
                   model.setValueAt(txtAno.getText(), i, 2);
                   model.setValueAt(txtGeneroMateria.getText(), i, 3);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Error al actualizar");
                }
            }
        });
        
        frame.setSize(900,400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       

 }
 
 
  
  
 

 public void setVisible(boolean b) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }


  
 }
```

Comment: Deberías conseguir la medalla [Informado](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed) que es tan sencilla de ganar como leer el [Recorrido completo](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender cómo funciona el sitio y cómo dar por respondida una pregunta, ya que tienes varias con respuestas pero no has aceptado ninguna aún. Esto es bueno para tí y la comunidad que te ha echado una mano. Además utilizas erroneamente la herramienta de insertar código. La que has usado es para código HTML/CSS/Javascript para ejecutarse y el tuyo es código Java. Utiliza Ctrl+K en su lugar.

Comment: No sabia de eso  gracias :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese mensaje no es un error. Simplemente eclipse informa que tu programa ha terminado. Este es un mensaje normal que se muestra cuando sale un programa. 
Si hubo un error, debería haber impreso algo en la consola en letras rojas como:

Excepción en el subproceso "main" java.lang.RuntimeException
     En testing.NFATest.main (NFATest.java:45)

O cualquier excepción que lanzó. (NullPointerException, ArrayIndexOutOfBounds, etc)

Comment: Ya habia leido eso en varios foros pero aún asi se me hace raro que no muestre el programa :/

Comment: No te funciona el programa??

Comment: No lo corre, solo sale el mensaje en la consola.

Comment: @MadyReyes  Voy a estar viendo un poco

Comment: Dentro de tu constructor WIndow al final de la linea, agrega esta linea frame.setVisible(true);  Es lo que faltaba, Eso nomas era. eje

Comment: @MadyReyes avisame si te funciono

Comment: Hice un codigo nuevo ya funciono. Gracias

Comment: El codigo que hice funciona todo, pero en la consola me aparece "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set a null TableModel" ¿Crees que haya un problema si lo dejo así?

Comment: @MadyReyes pero esa excepcion cuando te sale?? al iniciar el programa o al estar usando el programa??